# Interpreting regression inference trees

Tags: machine-learning, cart

I am working with the `ctree` function that is implemented in R in the `party` and `partykit` packages, and I have a question about working with the output. Here is an elementary example:

```
x <- ctree(mpg~.,mtcars)
plot(x)
```

[image]

If I understand correctly, the function uses its recursive algorithm to generate the splits, and then fits a regression for the distribution at each terminal node. A predicted value is generated by finding the the terminal node associated with the input, and then finding the predicted value from that regression.

Am I correct in assuming the algorithm generates a separate regression for each terminal node? So for example, predicting the value for a car with wt>2.32 would simply mean using the regression associated with the distribution in node 2. Similarly, for a car with wt<2.32 and disp<258 would use the regression from Node 4.

The plot gives me the distribution at each terminal node, but is it possible to extract the actual regression coefficients associated with a terminal node or am I misunderstanding how `ctree` works?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In conditional inference trees there is no regression model fitted in the nodes (unless you use a non-standard transformation function). Thus, in your example the prediction is simply based on the mean of the response in each terminal node.

If you want to fit a tree with regression models in each node, consider using `lmtree` or `glmtree` from the `partykit` package (based on the `mob` algorithm).

Comment: +1 Thanks for answering this one, Achim. You'd certainly be best placed to know (since you're a coauthor on the package), but this suggests that  the [index page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/party/index.html) for the documentation of `party` may be misleading for newcomers. It says: "*The core of the package is ctree(), an implementation of conditional inference trees which embed tree-structured regression models into*..." . It would hardly be a surprise if people interpreted that as doing regression at each node; indeed "embed" sees to suggest it.

Comment: Hmmm, `ctree` is still a regression tree (like `rpart` is), it just has a simple intercept-only model in each node. So the quote seems to fit and we didn't have many of such questions so far. But I'll have a look at whether we can improve the docs further.

Comment: I'd assume that the use of the word regression in the sentence there was really intended to refer to the model as a whole (which is a form of regression in the sense that globally it's a model for E(Y|predictors)... where in effect step-functions are being fitted); it's just that it's easy to read it as per-node regression there.